# Wrong data in file command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I try to write a script and after do:
`file imagefile.jpg`
i get wrong dimensions of a image:
`imagefile.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=8, yresolution=110, xresolution=118, height=0, orientation=upper-right, resolutionunit=2, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 4624x3472, components 3`
My image is in vertical orientation and here i got width > height. How can i find real dimensions of that image.

i tried file command, identify command. In Gnome properties dimensions are right.

Comment: I know nothing about JPEG metadata but there's some flag that indicates whether an image is _rotated_. In any case, I don't think `file` is the best tool to inspect picture files.

Comment: Which output were you expecting? On the other hand, you don't get width>height. You get width==hright (width=0 and height=0).

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

```
identify -format "%f %[EXIF:Orientation]" imagefile.jpg`
```

and its back code if it is rotated:

Exif Orientation values range from 1 to 8 and maps to orientation as below:

1 = Horizontal (normal)

2 = Mirror horizontal

3 = Rotate 180

4 = Mirror vertical

5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW

6 = Rotate 90 CW

7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW

8 = Rotate 270 CW